# How can I get unblocked from Apple CheckCoverage?

Tags: warranty, applecare

Apple has a website that allows you to [check warranty coverage/AppleCare status](https://checkcoverage.apple.com/ca/en/) by entering the serial number of an Apple device.

I was recently updating inventory records at the office where I work, and I think I used this tool too many times in a row because now I'm blocked. Since a week ago, every time I visit I am presented with this error message:

> **403 Forbidden**
>
> ---
>
> Apple

Who should I contact, or what can I do to get unblocked from this? And is there a better way for businesses to check warranty status on a larger amount of devices/serial numbers?

Comment: Have you tried contacting Apple? Usually there is a link on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would ask you Apple sales person to get you an account on Apple Business Manager. That one account will unlock all manner of goodness. You can then apply for customer seeding programs, get global service accounts to check serials and more.

- https://business.apple.com/

If you don’t have a business contact, just estimate how many Macs and Apple products you manage and call sales 1-800-MY-APPLE and ask for a referral or walk into an Apple Store and ask for the business team.

Your contact will then go to bat and either get you trained on the new tools or cleared from the abuse filter for the web page you triggered.

Comment: This is the best answer. Unfortunately my Apple business manager has been unable to help me with this issue so far.

Comment: It takes time to get through from ABM to then qualify for a GSX account, ask for a review from Apple monthly as you get used to the tool. Unless you don’t have enough computers for them to grant GSX, that’s the way to get this. Also, even with GSX if you are checking serials you didn’t buy, you’ll get banned no matter what. It’s a tool to manage your Macs

Answer (score 0):

Since this website works in a logged out state (thus very less association with account) and has a captcha to avoid bots, you might have tripped on such a denial of service.

You can use TOR browser or VPN to bypass this if it is tied to IP address.

If it is associated with browser, another one to use.

If device, you might be out of luck using the same device and end up talking to them.

Comment: This keeps banning other IP addresses. I’d get Apple to help - it’s worth the effort.